# How to activate and deactivate panels in an array of 20 Panels by clicking a button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a kids educational game.
I have 20 panels of questions. If answered correctly, A button is activated. If clicked on Button, next panel should be active and the last active panel should be deactivated. This should happen with all 20 panels.

The Code is as follows:

```
public class PanelChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject nextButton;
    public GameObject[] QuestionsPanel;
    public GameObject wellDonePanel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {

        QuestionsPanel[Random.Range(0, QuestionsPanel.Length)].SetActive(true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
   
    }

   ...
```

Here I want to place the code to activate the next panel and deactivate the active panel. In this code I am able to Set active random panel, but not able deactivate the current panel.

[image]

```
    ...
  
    public void ShowNextQuestion()
    {
        wellDonePanel.SetActive(false);
        QuestionsPanel[Random.Range(0, QuestionsPanel.Length)].SetActive(true);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either store the current panel in a field

```
private GameObject currentPanel;
```

and always do

```
// If a previous panel exists deactivate it
if(currentPanel) currentPanel.SetActive(false);

// Store the new panel
currentPanel = QuestionsPanel[Random.Range(0, QuestionsPanel.Length)];
// Activate the new panel
currentPanel.SetActive(true);
```

Or alternatively simply iterate the entire array and do

```
// Get the tendon index
var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, QuestionsPanel.Length);
// Iterate all panels
for(var i = 0; i < QuestionsPanel.Length; i++)
{
    // Set the matching panel active, all others inactive
    QuestionsPanel[i].SetActive(i == randomIndex);
}
```

---

Note though: Currently you might get the same panel twice in a row. If you only want to do all the panels in random order and then be finished rather randomize the array **once** and then simply iterate it in the randomized order sequentially like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

private GameObject [] randomizedQuestions;

private int currentIndex;
private GameObject currentPanel;

private void Start ()
{
    Shuffle ();
    ShowNextQuestion();
}

private void Shuffle()
{
    randomizedQuestions = QuestionPanel.OrderBy(p => Random.value).ToArray();
}

public void ShowNextQuestion ()
{
    if(currentIndex >= randomizedQuestions.Length)
    {
        // Up to you. You can either just stop
        Debug.LogWarning("No more questions available", this);
        return;

        // Or you could just start over 
        Shuffle();
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    if(currentPanel) currentPanel.SetActive(false);

    currentPanel = randomizedQuestions[currentIndex];

    currentPanel.SetActive(true);

    currentIndex++;      
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, You exactly suggested what I was looking for. Thank you.